# Update Product QTY right before place order from external remote API

Tags: magento2, product, stock, quantity

We want to update and check product quantity when user clicks on "Place Order" button. If product is outofstock in remote API and get 0 qty then user should not able to "Place Order" and display default error message.

Default Magento works that way and show message if we update qty through backend while customer is on "Place Order".

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom extension with following 2 files.

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">s
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="update_qty_from_api" type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\UpdateQtyFromApi" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Plugin/UpdateQtyFromApi.php

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;

class UpdateQtyFromApi
{
    public function __construct(
        QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    )
    {
        $this->callApi($cartId);

        return [$cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress];
    }

    public function callApi($cartId)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($cartId);

        $quoteItems = $quote->getAllItems();

        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $sku = $item->getProduct()->getSku();
            $qty = $this->getQtyFromCurlCall($sku);

            $this->updateQty($sku, $qty);
        }
    }

    public function getQtyFromCurlCall($sku)
    {
        // make your curl call here to get qty based on sku, and return that qty
        return 0;
    }

    public function updateQty($sku, $qty)
    {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
        $stockItem->setQty($qty);
        $stockItem->setIsInStock((bool)$qty);
        $this->stockRegistry->updateStockItemBySku($sku, $stockItem);
    }
}
```

Replace **{Vendor}** and **{Module}** with your actual vendor and module name. And also add your condition accordingly in code. This will not allow user to place order if your condition does not match with your API.

Hope this helps you !!!

Comment: we want to update qty from remote API before place an order.. so cases like if existing product has 10 qty at backend and through remote API we got 0 qty .. so when customer try to place an order it should update qty to 0 and show a message .

Comment: @siddhrock, Then you can load the product using product  model/repository and update the stock qty to that as per your api, The default magento should validate then. Check with that option.

Comment: We already tried that way to update qty, but it's not updating qty while clicking on "Place Order" .. we got qty from remote API and sales quantity as well.. but it's not updating it..

Comment: @siddhrock, can you please paste the code you did.

Comment: `<?php 
foreach ($items as $item) {       
$sku = $curldata['sku'];//api sku 
$prodcollectionsku = $this->_productRepository->get($sku); //using \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
$prodcollectionsku->setStockData(
        [ 
                'qty' => $curldata['quantity'],
  'manage_stock' => 1
         ]
        );
    $prodcollectionsku->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $curldata['quantity'], 'manage_stock' => 1]);
    try {
    $prodcollectionsku->save();
}
     catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error In Product Save" . $e->getMessage();
    }
}`

Comment: @siddhrock, check my updated answer. This must work for you !!!

Comment: thanks for your answer..

Comment: Please upvote and accept if that worked for you !!!

Comment: Please upvote question too